# Running PhantomJs from command prompt using C#

Tags: c#, phantomjs

I am trying to run `PhantomJs.exe` throw C# code.
My Code :

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\";
startInfo.Arguments = "some string code here";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

When I run it is going to WorkingDirectory `E:/` but Arguments are not writing on cmd prompt.

Can any buddy suggest me to run arguments on cmd.exe?

Comment: What is your string you tried as argument? Instead of `some string code here`

Comment: How do you decide that args not writing?

Comment: argument ="phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options1.json -outfile chart1.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 -constr Chart -callback callback.js"

Comment: Tommi: The code is running stressful without any error but the argument which i am passing that is not write/display on command prompt

Comment: So Process will run a code cmd phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options1.json -outfile chart1.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 -constr Chart -callback callback.js Why you not start phantomjs directly?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get cmd.exe to accept a further command as an argument, you need to precede that command with /K (if you want the cmd window to stay open) or /C (if you want the window to close after the command has completed). So:

```
argument ="/C phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options1.json -outfile chart1.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 -constr Chart -callback callback.js";
```

should do what you need.

However, if you just want to run the PhantomJS program, I agree with Tommi: just run that without starting a cmd.exe process first (i.e. use `startInfo.FileName = "phantomjs.exe";` instead.